# What does 'forms a right-handed set' mean?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

In a question I am reading, the following question appears.

> What if $\vec{A},\vec{B}$, and $\vec{C}$ are mutually perpendicular and form a right-handed set?

What exactly does "form a right-handed set" mean? That $\hat{A}\times\hat{B}=\hat{C}$? Or does it mean the stronger equality $\vec{A}\times \vec{B}=\vec{C}$?

Comment: It probably means that if you take the plane $P$ formed by the vectors $A$ and $B$, and you look down at $P$ from the side where it appears that $B$ is obtained by rotating $A$ counterclockwise, then $C$ emerges into the half-space determined by $P$ that you're looking at it from. (If you look at $P$ from the opposite side, then $B$ will appear to be obtained by rotating $A$ *clockwise*.)

Comment: It probably means the first one.

Comment: I would check the context of the statement very closely, but with no other context I assume it means that Ahat x Bhat = Chat, not Avec x Bvec = Cvec.  Again, read the full context of the quote.  For instance, if you're told to find magnitudes of these vectors, then surely it is the Avec... statement.

Comment: After searching a bit more online, I think @user208259 might be right. I think three vectors form a right-handed set if the third vector has a component in the direction perpendicular to the other two - not that they are necessarily perpendicular. They only become perpendicular when it is explicitly said (as is done in the question I cited).

Comment: The main question is which of the two half-spaces that perpendicular component is directed into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are accustomed to embed our  geometrical figures into the world around us, and in this environment the idea of "righhandedness" makes sense. But *mathematically* relevant is only "samehandedness", as follows:

Call two triples $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$, $\>(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ of linearly independent vectors in ${\mathbb R}^3$ (or any three-dimensional real vector space)  *equivalent* if the first triple can be continuously deformed into the second, such that at all times $t\in[0,1]$ the three vectors $a(t)$, $b(t)$, $c(t)$ are linearly independent. It turns out that there are exactly two equivalence classes, and that two triples are equivalent (or *equally oriented*) iff the matrix representing the one in terms of the other has positive determinant.

Usually one considers the standard basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$ as *positively oriented* and draws these three vectors in such a way that they seem "righthanded". Now for the cross product: Two linearly independent vectors $a$ and $b$ determine a two-dimensional plane whose orthogonal complement is a one dimensional vector space $L$, spanned by some vector $n\ne0$. Exactly one of $n$ and $-n$ complements $(a,b)$ to a positively oriented triple, and it is this choice of normal that is used in the definition of $a\times b$.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer (as was the other one). I chose this one because it gave a small bit more information.

Answer (score 3):

There are several equivalent definitions, but here is one that is often convenient:

The ordered triplet $(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C)$ of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is right called right-handed if $\det(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C)>0$, where $(\vec A,\vec B,\vec C)$ is the square matrix formed by taking the three vectors as columns.
(Note that the determinant is necessarily nonzero since you assumed the vectors to be orthogonal and (hopefully also) nonzero.)
Similarly the triplet is left-handed if the determinant is negative.
The triplet is linearly dependent if the determinant is zero.

This generalizes to any dimension: we can easily define what it means for a $n$-tuplet of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ to be right-handed.
If you multiply each vector in the multiplet by the same invertible square matrix, handedness is preserved if the matrix has positive determinant and reversed if negative.

Some intuitive properties are easy to observe from this point of view:
If you interchange any two vectors in the multiplet, the handedness is reversed.
If you permute the vectors cyclically, handedness is preserved.

Comment: This was a very great answer.

Comment: As an engineer, this answer is a lot more clear than the accepted one